# Jquery hover not working, doesnt add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

i was hoping someone could take a look at my code and tell me whats wrong..

HTML5:

```
<div class="btn-group" id="dropdown-wrapper">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="toggle-dropdown">Het 10-stappenplan <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Stap 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stap 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stap 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stap 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stap 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stap 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stap 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stap 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stap 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stap 10</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a#toggle-dropdown").hover(function () {
        $("a#toggle-dropdown").addClass("test");
    })
});
```

i hope anyone can tell what i did wrong, i cant see to find out what i did wrong..

the Jquery is gonna be a bit different that this, because i want it to add the class open to the .btn-group whenever the user hovers over the a#toggle-dropdown.

Comment: your code seems fine. Is a#toggle-dropdown loaded at some point?

Comment: Wild guess: you have multiple elements with the same ID (`toggle-dropdown`) in your page.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this, it works!

Comment: this will add class only when you hover so you cant see

Comment: not sure what you mean by loading a#toggle, no multiple elements, and i added some css to see if it works on hover

Comment: Not related to issue but seems like you are confusing `hover in/out` method with `mouseover` event

Comment: Works fine.. Check **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/1mh9v0mb/1/)**

Comment: @DennisHeitinga IDs must be unique on document context, you cannot have more than one element with same ID. Not sure it is related to your issue because you didn't provide miinimalistic sample code to replicate your issue, as you should. Now just wondering, are you using any plugin? Is this element dynamically added to the DOM? Etc...

Comment: this is the only jquery on the page so far, everything else is just plain html5 and CSS

Comment: @DennisHeitinga So your issue comes from somewhere else. Error in console?

Comment: Ok but how do you check than class isn't added? If using any CSS rule, why don't you post it in question? What about setting a jsFiddle to replicate your issue? What can we say?!

Comment: i added the css rule later on, said that somewhere in the comments here

Answer (score 4):

Using JS for hover effects is *not always* a good idea, instead use CSS if you can:

```
#toggle-dropdown
{
  // non-hovered style effects
}

#toggle-dropdown:hover
{
  // alternate effects
}
```

This is far quicker especially when you have many many tags.

To highlight all links:

```
.dropdown-menu a
{
  background-color: #cccccc; // light grey
}

.dropdown-menu a:hover
{
  background-color: #ff0000; // red
}
```

The reasons not to use CSS but JS are very limited:

- you do NOT use an anchor (`<a>`) tag
- AND you want compatibilty with IE8 and earlier

If you use an `<a>` anchor tag there really is NO reason to not use CSS.

In all other cases, the CSS way is to prefer.

If you can (as you already use jQuery) do the last step to standard and conformity and use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), it is very useful in your case but requires some up-front learning. Trust me, it will **pay off** in all HTML web pages you will write from there on.

Comment: Good point but as OP said `the Jquery is gonna be a bit different that this, because i want it to add the class open to the .btn-group whenever the user hovers over the a#toggle-dropdown.` CSS only wouldn't be a solution because you cannot target parent in CSS

Comment: im already using bootstrap, this dropdown thing was a snippet, but it shows the menu onclick, and the owner wants it to show on hover, and i know how to work with pseudo classes in CSS, but didnt think i can show the menu with CSS

Answer (score 3):

What you need,

```
$("a#toggle-dropdown").hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("test"); // use this instead
});
```

```js
$("a#toggle-dropdown").hover(function () {
   $(this).addClass("test"); // use this instead
});
```

```css
.test{
   color:#0CF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group" id="dropdown-wrapper">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="toggle-dropdown">Het 10-stappenplan <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Stap 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stap 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stap 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stap 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stap 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stap 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stap 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stap 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stap 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Stap 10</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But its better to use CSS effects as @pid suggests like,

```
a#toggle-dropdown
{
     color:#CCC;
}

a#toggle-dropdown:hover
{
     color:#FFF;
}
```

Also I think you need to add `open` class to the `ul drop-down` like

```
$("a#toggle-dropdown").hover(function () {
    $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').addClass("open"); // add open class to show
},function(){
    $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').removeClass("open"); // remove open to hide it
});
```

Comment: not working, i added css to .test to change the bgcolor to red, but no effect

Comment: try `alert(window.jQuery);` to check the library is added or not. See my working snippet.

Comment: May be, remove the extra closing `span tag` from your anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Id should be unique, so you can use only $("#toggle-dropdown") instead of $("a#toggle-dropdown");

Let's try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#toggle-dropdown" ).on("hover", function() {
        $(this).addClass("test");
    });
});
```